# Faces vs. font-lock faces

Tags: faces, font-lock

What is the relationship between the ["basic" faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Faces.html#Basic-Faces) defined in `faces.el` and ["font-lock" faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html) in `font-lock.el`?

My initial impression was that basic faces, like `bold` and `fixed-pitch`, are based on *style* rather than *semantics*. The font-lock faces, in contrast, are based on semantics rather than style.

Closer inspection shows that this is not accurate, however. For example, there is both a `warning` face in `faces.el` and a `font-lock-warning-face` in `font-lock.el`. There are also some basic faces, like `success` and `error`, that are clearly semantic, but without font-lock counterparts.

Is there anything more than historical accident (font-lock, I believe, was introduced by [XEmacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmacs), an Emacs fork) that there are two sets of general-purpose faces? Would it be desirable to unify them into a single set? Are there any plans to do so?

Comment: They are all just faces; nothing more. And in spite of those two manual nodes, there are not "two sets of general-purpose faces" (IMHO). There are simply some predefined faces, which are used by some predefined code in some predefined ways. You can use those faces in those ways. Or you can use those faces in other ways. Or you can use other faces (which you create). It is worth learning how such faces are used by existing code. And the doc is your friend here too. But whatever these faces are or do so far does not limit what you do with them (or not).

Comment: Good point that there's more than "two sets" of faces. But I think these are not "just faces", if only because of established conventions. For example, it is standard to use font-lock faces for syntax highlighting; many themes, etc. rely on this.

Comment: Yes, it's just historical accident.  BTW, AFAIK font-lock was introduced for both Emacs and XEmacs at the same time (not sure which one bundled it first: XEmacs development was probably a bit faster back then, so I'd guess it was XEmacs).

Comment: I think it'd be good if there was a comprehensive set of semantic faces. Have any attempts been made in this area? Are there any conventions about naming faces (end in `-face`)?